# batch add silence to wav files using ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, batch

I have a whole awful lot of wav soundfiles that i need to add 0.05 seconds of silence to the very end.

The soundfiles should not in any way be altered except for that 0.05 second silence at the end. Which means that the HZ, bit depth and volume level must remain the same.

Is it possible to have a batch script for windows which will load up a wav file, add 0.05s of silence to the end and save it in a new subfolder and then load the next wav until all are processed?

Answer (score 4):

I have found a solution. I tried ffmpeg with the following code, which did not work because apparently "pad_dur" does not exist.

```
for %%F in (*.wav) do ffmpeg -i "%%F" -af "apad=pad_dur=5" "new\%%F"
```

So instead i used

```
for %%F in (*.wav) do ffmpeg -i "%%F" -af "apad=pad_len=2134" "new\%%F"
```

Which is not quite 0.05 seconds, but 0.049. which is good enough.

If you find a better way please let me know!

Comment: Upgrade your ffmpeg. `pad_dur` is newer than the 4.1 release branch, so use a build from the current master branch.

Comment: i have 4.1.3 which is the newesti could find on the ffmpeg page.

Comment: On [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page go to "get the packages" choose your OS and then follow the links to pre-compiled builds. They all provide a "git/nightly/snapshot" of the current master branch. Or refer to "Get the Sources" and compile.